# lighttpd/fastcgi/python errors in logs

Tags: python, lighttpd, web.py, fastcgi

I'm running a web.py app on Lighttpd and noticed ajax requests occasionally failing (sometimes they're fine, sometimes not) - so I had a look at the error log and found it riddled with this:

```
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     return p(lambda: process(processors))
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 85, in _processor
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     self._load()
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 106, in _load
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     d = self.store[self.session_id]
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 250, in __getitem__
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     return self.decode(pickled)
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 210, in decode
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     return pickle.loads(pickled)
2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr: EOFError
```

Has anyone encountered these errors before?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the code (at least the Ajaxed part)

Answer (score -1):

edit this file:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()                                                          


class DiskStore(Store): 
     .......
     .......

     def __getitem__(self, key):                                                  
         path = self._get_path(key)                                               
         if os.path.exists(path):                                                 
             lock.acquire()                                                       
             f = open(path)                                                       
             try:                                                                 
                 pickled = f.read()
                 return self.decode(pickled)                                      
             finally:                                                             
                 f.close()                                                        
                 lock.release()                                                   
         else:                                                                    
             raise KeyError, key                                                  

     def __setitem__(self, key, value):                                           
         path = self._get_path(key)                                               
         pickled = self.encode(value)                                             
         try:                                                                     
             lock.acquire()                                                       
             f = open(path, 'w')                                                  
             try:                                                                 
                 f.write(pickled)                                                 
             finally:                                                             
                 f.close()                                                        
                 lock.release()                                                       
         except IOError:                                                          
             lock.release()                                                       
             pass
```

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     return p(lambda: process(processors))

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 85, in _processor

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     self._load()

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 106, in _load

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     d = self.store[self.session_id]

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 250, in **getitem**

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     return self.decode(pickled)

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 210, in decode

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr:     return pickle.loads(pickled)

2014-07-02 17:22:33: (mod_fastcgi.c.2673) FastCGI-stderr: EOFError